# Can't I show advertisements in my app without adding payment method in admob?

Tags: android, admob

Can't I show advertisements in my app without adding payment method in admob ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @anilk.c was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can but they may stop or limit ads serving after you get your first $100 or after a while until you add a payment method.

My advice is to add payment method as soon as possible.